# Repeating Reminders on desktop won't stay in sync with iOS

Tags: macos, iphone, reminders

When I create a reminder that is set to repeat, for example:

```
"take out the garbage" repeat every 2 weeks.
```

it pops up on my phone and on my desktop.

When I check it off on my phone, my computer never gets the message that it was checked off. If I check it off on my computer, my phone never gets the message that it was checked off.

I'm running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2 and iOS 6.0.1 on an iPhone 4S.

This has never worked for me and I've been through several versions of each OS.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Reminders supports iCloud but does not require it. Have you checked on your iPhone that Reminders is using iCloud? Go to Settings > iCloud and ensure Reminders is on.

Comment: bneely , I checked and it is on. I assumed it was though because when I create a reminder on my phone, it will show on my computer and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this.

On iOS I went to SETTINGS > ICLOUD > Turned Reminders OFF, then ON. It warned me that it would delete my reminders.. No big deal as they are still stored on iCloud.

On OSX I went to System Preferences... > iCloud > unchecked Calendars & Reminders ( it again warned me that it would delete them from computer which is okay because they are stored on iCloud) > Checked Calendars & Reminders (to turn them back on.)

It is now working as expected. Weird...